How to make a simple materialized view fast-refreshable?
I have the following code
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW AB 
REFRESH FAST
AS
SELECT
    A.ID
    B.ELIGIBLE_YN
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ENTITY_ID;

But I get the following error:
ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query
12015. 00000 -  "cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query"
*Cause:    Neither ROWIDs and nor primary key constraints are supported for
           complex queries.
*Action:   Reissue the command with the REFRESH FORCE or REFRESH COMPLETE
           option or create a simple materialized view.

I've tried adding materialized view logs:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON A WITH PRIMARY KEY, SEQUENCE, ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON B WITH PRIMARY KEY, SEQUENCE, ROWID(ENTITY_ID, ELIGIBLE_YN) INCLUDING NEW VALUES;


ANSI JOINs support in materialized views has started only with version 23, before you have to use old syntax
FROM A, B WHERE A.ID = B.ENTITY_ID(+)

And you have dbms_mview.explain_mview to get more info on the reasons why your MV is not fast refresh-able.

It looks like you're missing a comma after "A.ID"?
    SELECT
    A.ID,
    B.ELIGIBLE_YN
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ENTITY_ID;

